# BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand. KeyError: 'email'

Tags: html, sqlite, flask

I'm creating website that books bus tickets, it lists destinations and time. When I execute my flask code every pages executes well except the book.html page somehow it keeps self re-directing to the home.html page and displays a error message that is listed in the title, for better view here is the screenshot of the error message [error message display screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H72UM.png)
here are pictures of my two db browser for sqlite database tables [database tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHKc8.png), (https://i.stack.imgur.com/d25hv.png)

flask code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
import sqlite3 
import os

currentdirectory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/home")
def home():
        return render_template("home.html")

@app.route("/home", methods = ["POST", "GET"])
def myhome():
     if request.method =="POST":
        email = request.form["email"]
        password = request.form["password"]
        connection = sqlite3.connect(currentdirectory + "\database.db")
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        query1 = "SELECT username, password from Users_Details WHERE username = '{un}' AND password = '{pw}'".format(un = email, pw = password)
     
        cursor.execute(query1)
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        if len(rows) == 0:
          print("try again")
        else:
         return render_template("book.html")
      
     return render_template("home.html")
@app.route("/signup", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def signup():
     if request.method == "POST":
          email = request.form["email"]
          password = request.form["password"]
          number = request.form["number"]
          address = request.form["address"]
          connection = sqlite3.connect(currentdirectory + "\database.db")
          cursor = connection.cursor()
          query1 = "INSERT INTO Users_Details VALUES('{E}','{P}',{N},'{A}')".format(E = email, P = password, N = number, A = address)
          cursor.execute(query1)
          connection.commit()
          return redirect("/home")
     
     return render_template("signup.html")

          


@app.route("/book", methods =["GET","POST"])
def book():
    if request.method == "POST":
        destinations = request.form["destinations"]
        time = request.form["time"]
        connection = sqlite3.connect(currentdirectory + "\database.db")
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        query1 = "INSERT INTO timeTable VALUES('{d}',{t})".format( d = destinations, t = time)
        cursor.execute(query1)
        connection.commit()
        return redirect("/confirmation")
     
    return render_template("book.html")


@app.route("/confirmation")
def confirmation():
    return render_template("confirmation.html")

if __name__ =="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

book.html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>vut website bus shuttle ticket booking</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="head">
        <img src="/static/images/logo.png" alt="vut logo">
        <h1>Book Your Ticket Below</h1>
        <h4>Contact Us: <br>064 304 5858</h4>
    </div>
        <form action="#" method ="POST" class="form-row"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="select">
                <label>
                <h4>From Campus To:</h4>
                <select name="destinations" class="block" required>
                    <option class="choose">Choose A Res....</option>
                    <option>Amberfield</option>
                    <option>Park Village</option>
                    <option>Park Square</option>
                    <option>Good Year</option>
                    <option>SunTrust</option>
                    <option>GreenWays</option>
                </select>
                </label>

                    <h4>Time:</h4>
                <select name="time" class="block" required>
                    <option class="choose" selected disabled>Choose Departure Time</option>
                    <option>09:15</option>
                    <option>10:15</option>
                    <option>11:15</option>
                    <option>12:15</option>
                    <option>14:15</option>
                    <option>15:15</option>
                    <option>17:15</option>
                    <option>19:15</option>
                </select><br>
                
                <div class="block">
                  <input   type="submit"  class="book-btn" name="book" value="BOOK">
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </form>
            

    
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unless you're uploading a file, don't use `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: @Phil Ow yeah thanks for noticing that, I actually inserted that thinking it will solve my problem, so with or without it my problem still remains unsolved

Answer (score 0):

After successful login in the “myhome” route you are displaying the book.html page directly from within that route rather than redirecting to the correct “book” route. This displays the page correctly but the url remains unchanged so the data is posted back to “myhome” rather than “book”. Replace the render_template(“book.html”) with redirect(url_for(“book”)) and the page will be displayed under the correct url and your post should work correctly.

Comment: I did as you said and when i try running it i received this following error                              File "C:\Users\sechm\Desktop\Project\app.py", line 63, in book
cursor.execute(query1)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ":15": syntax error